# How to wrap widget inside ListViewBuilder in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'd Wrap horizontal listview builder, 
my code :

```
return ListView.builder(
            // shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: ayahQuran[110]['ayat'].length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Wrap(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      ayahQuran[110]['ayat'][index]["ayat_ayat"]                 
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                        ayahQuran[110]['ayat'][index]["noayat"].toString()),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          );
```

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkAou.png)

I want to like this :
[want to like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYwmd.jpg)

I have tried much time to this, anyone can help me to fix it.
thanks

Comment: Hi @Nanang Kho and welcome ! it isn't very clear what you want to achieve. Could provide further explanation than the linked image ? So that people can better help you :)

Comment: In my code listview scroll horizontal, I want to wrap in new line.

Answer (score 0):

> In my code listview scroll horizontal, I want to wrap in new line.

EDIT : so what is asked is to keep elements aligned horizontaly, but with the ability to scroll verticaly.

**To keep the vertical scroll :** 
you need to set `scrollDirection` to `Axis.vertical`. But since this is the default value, you can simply remove this line from your code: `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,`.

**To align elements horizontaly:** you must put them into a `Row` widget.

example :

```
return ListView.builder(
            // shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: ayahQuran[110]['ayat'].length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Wrap(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          ayahQuran[110]['ayat'][index]["ayat_ayat"]                 
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                        ayahQuran[110]['ayat'][index]["noayat"].toString(),
                         ),
                       ),
                     ],
                   ),
                 ],
               );
             },
           );
```

Comment: if set `scrollDirection ` to `Axis.vertical ` it will like column, I want to like row but scroll to vertical.

Comment: its same still scroll horizontal, [https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BUNyl9_L4RzpdQZ2lFB3m65LclQUu3SI]

Comment: your link does not work, please show your code instead :) have you removed `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,` ?

Comment: if I remove `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal` it seem like column,.
this my code :
`return ListView.builder(
// shrinkWrap: true,
scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
itemCount: quranData[110]['ayat'].length,
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
return Wrap(
children: <Widget>[
Row(
children: <Widget>[
Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
child: Text(quranData[110]['ayat'][index]["ayat"]    
),
),
Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
child: Text(quranData[110]['ayat'][index]["no"]
.toString()),
 ),
 ],
),
 ],
);
 },
);`

Comment: if not remove `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal` scroll horizontal not wrap in new line